# How to get minut sensor data every 15 minutes

Tags: c#, button

I have hosted my website which uses C# onto the azure cloud, the website needs me to click on the button whenever I wanted to get the latest sensor update, I am wondering if I am able to get the sensor update every 15 minutes from Monday to Friday only without clicking a button?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of this will depend on exactly what/how you are interacting with elements.  But for something that is scheduled, especially on a frequency as you mention creating a [WebJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create) that goes along with your web application and is set to a 15 minute interval is most likely the best option to get the scheduling with the least effort.